# instagram_business_account ID missing on Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i test my app on the Graph Explorer the instagram_business_account id doesn't appear in my list...
We manage several facebook pages, and some others work fine with same parameters.

I have all the permissions needed, manage_pages business_management and instagram_basic.
I already tried to to go back to personal instagram account and then business again but it doesn't change anything...

Any new solution for this known issue?

ref : https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/177912116363088/?disable_redirect=0

Comment: Weird fact : i tried to create an app directly with my client access, and then his instagram ID is here... maybe a right issue for administrators?

Answer (score -1):

JULY 2023 UPDATE:

For Instagram accounts added/linked via Facebook Business Suite/Assets now you need `business_management` permission. Check this [support thread](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/780004130341035).

OLD INFO:

Try to add `pages_read_engagement` permission to your auth request. You don't need `manage_pages` just to get Instagram ID, its overkill.